# Equality case in the subadditive property of Expected Shortfall

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, distribution-tails, risk-assessment

If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are two $L^1$ real-values random variables, it is well known that

$ES_\alpha(Z_1+Z_2) \le ES_\alpha(Z_1) + ES_\alpha(Z_2)$ for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$

However, what about the equality case? I see two cases:

- one of the random variables is constant
- random variables are proportional

Are there other cases?

Comment: It works with comonotone variables as well. Is that necessary?